# Button in JTable won't perform action

Tags: java, button, jtable, renderer

I have a `JTable` where I have inserted two buttons (delete, search) in each row.
For each button I specify the proper action in my constructor like this:

```
        Action search = new AbstractAction() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JTable table = (JTable) e.getSource();
            int modelRow = Integer.valueOf(e.getActionCommand());
            System.out.println("Search action for row: " + modelRow);

            // do some processing here
            // tb.searchMore(modelRow);
        }
    };
```

And then I specify to which column the button should be created like this:

```
    // column 4 of JTable table should implement action 'search'
    ButtonColumn searchButtonColumn = new ButtonColumn(table, search, 4);
    searchButtonColumn.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_D);
```

And I have a proper Button Renderer Class. 
The delete button (which is being created and initialized exactly the same way) works just fine. So does a similar save button I created for another table. 
The problem is with the search button. It creates the graphic button in the table, but its action is never actualluy being called. I noticed that this happens when I place it in a column other that the very first one. Any ideas for this strange behaviour? The column I am placing it is not out of bounds. Is there a problem with placing two buttons in tha same row?

Below is the Button Renderer code:

```
public class ButtonColumn extends AbstractCellEditor
    implements TableCellRenderer, TableCellEditor, ActionListener, MouseListener {

private JTable table;
private Action action;
private int mnemonic;
private Border originalBorder;
private Border focusBorder;
private JButton renderButton;
private JButton editButton;
private Object editorValue;
private boolean isButtonColumnEditor;

/**
 *  Create the ButtonColumn to be used as a renderer and editor. The
 *  renderer and editor will automatically be installed on the TableColumn
 *  of the specified column.
 *
 *  @param table the table containing the button renderer/editor
 *  @param action the Action to be invoked when the button is invoked
 *  @param column the column to which the button renderer/editor is added
 */
public ButtonColumn(JTable table, Action action, int column) {
    this.table = table;
    this.action = action;

    renderButton = new JButton();
    editButton = new JButton();
    editButton.setFocusPainted(false);
    editButton.addActionListener(this);
    originalBorder = editButton.getBorder();
    setFocusBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLUE));

    TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();
    columnModel.getColumn(column).setCellRenderer(this);
    columnModel.getColumn(column).setCellEditor(this);
    table.addMouseListener(this);
}

/**
 *  Get foreground color of the button when the cell has focus
 *
 *  @return the foreground color
 */
public Border getFocusBorder() {
    return focusBorder;
}

/**
 *  The foreground color of the button when the cell has focus
 *
 *  @param focusBorder the foreground color
 */
public void setFocusBorder(Border focusBorder) {
    this.focusBorder = focusBorder;
    editButton.setBorder(focusBorder);
}

public int getMnemonic() {
    return mnemonic;
}

/**
 *  The mnemonic to activate the button when the cell has focus
 *
 *  @param mnemonic the mnemonic
 */
public void setMnemonic(int mnemonic) {
    this.mnemonic = mnemonic;
    renderButton.setMnemonic(mnemonic);
    editButton.setMnemonic(mnemonic);
}

@Override
public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(
        JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
    if (value == null) {
        editButton.setText("");
        editButton.setIcon(null);
    } else if (value instanceof Icon) {
        editButton.setText("");
        editButton.setIcon((Icon) value);
    } else {
        editButton.setText(value.toString());
        editButton.setIcon(null);
    }

    this.editorValue = value;
    return editButton;
}

@Override
public Object getCellEditorValue() {
    return editorValue;
}

//
//  Implement TableCellRenderer interface
//
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
        JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int  column) {
    if (isSelected) {
        renderButton.setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
        renderButton.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
    } else {
        renderButton.setForeground(table.getForeground());
        renderButton.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Button.background"));
    }

    if (hasFocus) {
        renderButton.setBorder(focusBorder);
    } else {
        renderButton.setBorder(originalBorder);
    }

//      renderButton.setText( (value == null) ? "" : value.toString() );
    if (value == null) {
        renderButton.setText("");
        renderButton.setIcon(null);
    } else if (value instanceof Icon) {
        renderButton.setText("");
        renderButton.setIcon((Icon) value);
    } else {
        renderButton.setText(value.toString());
        renderButton.setIcon(null);
    }

    return renderButton;
}

//
//  Implement ActionListener interface
//
/*
 *  The button has been pressed. Stop editing and invoke the custom Action
 */
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    int row = table.convertRowIndexToModel(table.getEditingRow());
    fireEditingStopped();

    //  Invoke the Action

    ActionEvent event = new ActionEvent(table,
            ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, "" + row);
    action.actionPerformed(event);
}

//
//  Implement MouseListener interface
//
/*
 *  When the mouse is pressed the editor is invoked. If you then then drag
 *  the mouse to another cell before releasing it, the editor is still
 *  active. Make sure editing is stopped when the mouse is released.
 */
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    if (table.isEditing()
            && table.getCellEditor() == this) {
        isButtonColumnEditor = true;
    }
}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    if (isButtonColumnEditor
            && table.isEditing()) {
        table.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing();
    }

    isButtonColumnEditor = false;
}

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
}

public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
}

public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you forgot to set the action command to the rendered button. You rely on that command in your action. Try something like

```
editButton.setActionCommand(String.valueOf(column));
```

in your cell renderer.

Comment: Well I finally found the problem. The renderer is ok but I had set the particular cell/column as non editable.. Thanks anyway @omgBob!